# PHP Refactoring, too many methods in class?

Tags: php, refactoring

I'm still fairly new to PHP and my project is still quite small. I was plodding along, learning as I go, but my code was starting to get messy, so I started reading about refactoring. The first thing I realised is that some of my functions were doing too much, so I split them into smaller, single-purpose functions. That's nice and helped make my code easier to read. But then I was getting concerned because I was putting each function into it's own little file and adding it to the 'includes', so that was getting messy. I realised that most of these functions could/should be methods in a class, so I did that. But now I have dozens of methods in some classes and it's starting to get messy again.

So in my example, I have a Soccer management game, which has teams and players. The `Team` class, at the moment, is dealing with database management for the teams (loading, saving and creating teams). I'm now working on having the AI pick it's own squad, so the class also has a `Picksquad` method, which is itself broken into about 6 methods. Is this the sort of thing that should go into it's own class, so I'd have something like a `Team Database` class and a `Team Selection` class or something?

The reason I'm confused (I think), is that I don't really understand how this 2nd class would work. Would it just be a class with no properties and a few functions and I pass a team object into it? So I have my team in an object, I want the AI to pick a squad, so I create a `Teamselect` object too and pass the team object into the teamselect methods? So it'd be like `teamselect->pickSquad($Teamobject)`? So the new class is just a bunch of methods, just for tidiness? Couldn't that be achieved with seperate functions, added through includes (although I've found that very messy too).

Apologies for the long-winded question. I know my thinking is off somewhere so I'd appreciate any simple answers. Please treat me as a noob to PHP because I am :)

Comment: This is probably going to get flagged as "off topic" - however, try giving this a read, it might help you get your head around OOP design principles : https://scotch.io/bar-talk/s-o-l-i-d-the-first-five-principles-of-object-oriented-design

Comment: Thanks, I'll do more reading. Why's it 'off topic', just too long-winded?

Comment: Too broad and opinion based and there is no code.

Comment: Hmm ok, I see what you mean. If my assumption is correct though, I don't mind the opinions, rather, is my solution workable?

Comment: SO is basically about solving specific problems with code not coding design principles as such ... there doesn't appear to be a Stack Exchange for that :| Which is unfortunate because I'd love someone to tell me if I'm right in thinking that every PHP framework seems to get *Models*, in the traditional sense, wrong :)

Comment: More about the right place for architecture questions: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/124867/where-should-i-ask-software-architecture-design-questions

Comment: @P0rnflake : thanks for that! Led me to finding the exact thing that's been bugging me for a while :D  http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/2806/is-mvc-just-the-seo-of-php-programming